# Is it possible to make a call to a partial view from the main view at the same time return JSON (ID) back to the main view

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Example - On button click

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var flag = false;
    var b;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Test/PV1/' + $('#Elements').val(),
        data: null,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.pageID);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

In the controller

```
public ActionResult PV1(int id)
{
    //-- here i need to make a call to the partial view as well as return the pageID to the main view
}
```

Is it possible to make a call to a partial view from the main view at the same time return JSON (ID) back to the main view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bubble the event up from your partial to your parent (although its not usually considered best practice).

ie. 
In your parent, have a function to set the ID to something.
Then in your partial, onSuccess, call that function.

eg.

**Parent View**

```
function doSomethingWithId(id){
    // do whatever you wanted to with the id now that its in the parent view
}
```

**Partial View**

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
var flag = false;
var b;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Test/PV1/' + $('#Elements').val(),
    data: null,
    success: function (data) {
        doSomethingWithId(data.pageID);
    }
});
return false;
```

});